# How can I exclude a vendor type using a ternary or unless?

Tags: shopify, liquid

In a `page.[].liquid` template there are numerous 'vendor' products to be listed. Some with and some without a collection association.

How can I exclude a specific vendor in a for loop using 'unless' or a ternary?

Neither of the following generate any output within the parent container.

```
<div style="height: 50px;" class="ptest">

  {% assign collection = product.available %}
  {% for product in collection.all_vendors %}
    {% if product.collection != "acme" %}
     <div>yes</div>
     {{ product.name }}
    {% else %}
      <div>no</div>
      {{ product.name }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% for product in collection.all_vendors  %}
    {% unless product.vendor contains "acme" %}
     <div>yes</div>
     {{ product.name }}
    {% else %}
      <div>no</div>
      {{ product.name }}
    {% endunless %}
  {% endfor %}

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

List all vendors except "acme":

```
{%- for vendor in collection.all_vendors -%}
  {%- if vendor == "acme" -%}
    {%- continue -%}
  {%- endif -%}

  {{ vendor }} is definitely not "acme"<br>
{%- endfor %}
```

List collection products except those with vendor "acme":

```
{%- for product in collection.products -%}
  {%- if product.vendor == "acme" -%}
    {%- continue -%}
  {%- endif -%}

  {{ product.name }} vendor is {{ product.vendor }}.<br>
{%- endfor -%}
```

---

Sorry, but your code is a mess:

- `{% assign collection = product.available %}` - the collection is now boolean, either `true` or `false`
- `{% for product in collection.all_vendors %}` - as of the above `collection` doesn't have `all_vendors` attribute.
- `{% if product.collection != "acme" %}` - as of the above, this code will never be reached, but even if it will - the `product` object doesn't have `collection` attribute.
- `{{ product.name }}` - where did you get this code? `product` doesn't have `name` attribute, you have to use `title` instead.
- `{% for product in collection.all_vendors  %}` - you go through vendors, why do you call them products?
- `{% unless product.vendor contains "acme" %}` - as this is the next line after the above one, the `product` would be a vendor, not a product object, so you should use it as a string i.e. `{% unless product contains "acme" %}`

Comment: You definitely opened my eyes to where my other languages were confusing me with Liquid. I was under the impression of a lot of things that don't ring true. However, unfortunately your solutions did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching, it looks like the only solution to displaying products that A. are 'all except' a single vendor and B. are not part of any collection, is to use a more simple if-math.

```
    {% for product in collections.all.products %}
      {% if product.collections.size < 1 && product.vendor != "acme" %}
            <h3>
              <a href="{{ product.url }}">
                {{ product.title }}
              </a>
            </h3>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Running through all products to loop those that are not part of a collection, generates the proper result.

Comment: Note that this may not work perfectly for collections with a large number of products. I believe the default pagination for collections.products is 50 items, so this loop will only list vendors that appear in the first 50 products (unless this is wrapped in `paginate` tags, in which case it will be limited to whatever the pagination `limit` is set to)

Comment: Great footnote. I've wrapped it in paginate, but not with parameters. Currently working on cycling through 1 product per vendor now.